# Can I get vertical / side tabs in Chrome on Mac?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, tabs, sidebar

Can I get vertical / side tabs in Chrome on Mac?

Right now it's Chrome 8 on OS X 10.6.

Comment: In Windows, you type "about:flags" (without quotes) into the url bar, then enable side tabs there.

Comment: `about:flags` loads other things in Mac, but not a vertical tab option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@blsub6 isn't that far off, but the instructions are for Windows, and it's quite different for Mac OS X, since *you cannot ordinarily specify command line arguments for applications you start*.

If you open `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`, you can open Chrome 8 with side tabs support by entering the following:

```
/path/to/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome -enable-vertical-tabs
```

[image]

You can wrap this call in an `Automator` application by using the *Run Shell Script* action there, and put this e.g. in your Dock. It won't be seamless, but good enough(tm).

[image]

Comment: This seems brilliant but I get an odd error message from the terminal call. Chrome loads, but if I close the terminal it closes too, and that drop-down menu does not appear. Any idea why it might be getting the errors? Maybe an errant extension or plugin? I'll post the error message in the subsequent comment; it's too long for this one. Thanks!

Comment: **first it says**  
[0101/174000:INFO:/b/build/slave/chrome-official-mac/build/src/chrome/app/breakpad_mac.mm(89)] Breakpad disabled  
**then it says**  
objc[1992]: Class **this varies** is implemented in both **long path** and **other long path**. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.  
**several times for several different classes, followed by**  
**date / time** Google Chrome Helper[1989:107] Error loading **path to /**DivX Decoder:  dlopen(**same path**, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 **same path again**: open() failed with errno=1  

**also several times**

Comment: @Philip The messages are nothing to worry about (except maybe the DivX issue which I don't have) -- if Chrome works fine, and the messages are the same with and without the additional parameters, don't worry about it. Chrome closing when you close the parent shell is normal and ugly, unfortunately I'm no Terminal expert and cannot provide relief, except the Automator solution I explained. You'll get the popup menu when you right-click on a tab, as in @blsub6's link.

Comment: Ohhh got it. Thanks! Hah! This is fairly ugly for now. (Do you also have the tab title spilling over the visual representation of the tab?) Can't wait until it really works though :) Thanks!

Comment: Actually just one other thing--maybe I'll put this in a separate question--is there a way to make that automator application close the automator icon automatically once it runs? If I manually quit it, it quits leaves Chrome open, which is good. But when I put "quit" for either automator or the named application as part of the workflow it simply won't close it. Thanks.

Comment: @Philip Add an ampersand (`&`) after the command.

Answer (score 1):

haven't tested in MacOS but...

http://www.chromeplugins.org/chrome/side-tabs-in-chrome/

Comment: Yeah like DB said Win only; first time in years I've been jealous of Windows users! :p

Answer (score 0):

There is an - as of now - nice Chrome extension called [Sidewise](http://www.sidewise.info/). On a Mac you should tick the checkbox "Focus the sidebar on mouse hover" for easier access. (single click on a tab name instead of double clicking.)